# XDK (2807) ios build fails when adding admobpro plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, admob, intel

when adding admobpro version 2.10.0(cordova-plugin-admobpro & cordova-plugin-admob) or admob plugin by appfeel, my ios build fails.
I h've tried a blank cordova project, and just added in plugin management the plugins one at the time. both fail.

here you can find the error log, provided by intel XDK.
https://gist.github.com/arjankuijpers/d3323f43e50ba0499c86

one of the lines read: The following build commands failed:
ios target: 6 (I have also tried 7)

android build succeed.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

It was an Xcode problem, because XDK used Xcode 6 instead of the new relied on version 7.
This is solved by Intel updating there build system.

a lot of plugins are only working with Xcode 7.
Be aware that ARM versions can make a difference.